# script uCurl table data using regular expression to send to a database

Tags: regex, linux, bash, curl, sed

I have a device on my network that is posting data to an html page.  I need to be able to collect the data from the page and insert it into my database so I can have historical reference to the data.

Below is an example of the html that the device presents.  The numbers that I am needing to pull are in the fields that currently have values 290, 1868 and 187.  They are in a table... the rows are identified by 5:1, 5:5 and 5:13 (if that helps at all).

I would like to run this as a linux cron job, so I would like to use a linux script to:
1.  pull the information from the site (assuming to use cUrl command)
2.  parse the data (assuming to use some type of regular expression command)
3.  save the data to variables
4.  connect to my database and insert the data in a table

I've tried several different things: curl + grep (I don't know that I fully understand sed or regex either.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
******start of html source
<html><head><title>Data Table Monitor</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff"><center>
<h2><font face="helvetica">Ethernet Processor</font></h2>
<h2><i>Data Table Monitor</i></h2>
<hr width=25% align=center>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="15"><body bgcolor="#ffffff"><center><table border=1><tr><th>Address</th><th>CU</th><th>CD</th><th>DN</th><th>OV</th><th>UN</th><th>UA</th><th>PRE</th><th>ACC</th><th>Address</th><th>CU</th><th>CD</th><th>DN</th><th>OV</th><th>UN</th><th>PRE</th><th>ACC</th></tr><tr><td>C5:0</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>10</td><td align=right>0</td><td>C5:1</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td><td align=right>290</td></tr><tr><td>C5:2</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td><td align=right>2</td><td>C5:3</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>0</td><td align=right>0</td></tr><tr><td>C5:4</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>0</td><td align=right>0</td><td>C5:5</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td><td align=right>1868</td></tr><tr><td>C5:6</td>
<td align=center>1</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td><td align=right>0</td><td>C5:7</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>0</td><td align=right>0</td></tr><tr><td>C5:8</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>0</td><td align=right>0</td><td>C5:9</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>0</td><td align=right>0</td></tr><tr><td>C5:10</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td><td align=right>717</td><td>C5:11</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td><td align=right>70</td></tr><tr><td>C5:12</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td><td align=right>187</td><td>C5:13</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td><td align=right>4384</td></tr><tr><td>C5:14</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td><td align=right>0</td><td>C5:15</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td><td align=right>0</td></tr><tr><td>C5:16</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td><td align=right>0</td><td>C5:17</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>32000</td><td align=right>1868</td></tr><tr><td>C5:18</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>0</td><td align=right>0</td><td>C5:19</td>
<td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=center>0</td><td align=right>0</td><td align=right>0</td></tr></table></center><hr width=25% align=center>
******end of html source
```

Answer (score 0):

use `C5:1<|C5:5<|C5:13` to identify the rows, then use look ahead `[0-9]+(?=..)` to capture only those digits

```
grep -Po '[0-9]+(?=[^0-9]+(C5:2<|C5:6<|C5:13))'
```

returns

```
290
1868
187
```

Comment: So here is the code I used: curl http://192.168.1.40/dtm.html?address=C5:0 | grep -Po '[0-9]+(?=</td><td align=right>[0-9]+</td><td>(C5:1<|C5:5<|C5:13))'   .... but it didn't return the numbers?  What am I missing?

Comment: I am probably doing something wrong.  When I run the previous command... this is my result:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1538    0  1538    0     0   8007      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  809410
0
32000
100  5666    0  5666    0     0  16826      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 16913

Comment: @user3727435, use `curl -s 192.168.1.40/dtm.html?address=C5:0` to silence the progress bar

Comment: It looks like it is pulled the numbers from the correct row, but a different column.  Do you have any suggestions.  The suggestion of adding the -s did work for silencing the progress bar.

Comment: @user3727435, oops, answer updated, please try this one

Comment: We are getting closer.  Now it appears to be pulling the number from the column directly in front of the "C5:1", but the number I need is at the end of the line.  It is kind of a confusing table.

Comment: @user3727435, yes. it pulls data from the same line. you just need to specify the right line by changing `C5:1<` to `C5:2<`

Comment: I tried the following command and it returned nothing:  curl -s http://192.168.1.40/dtm.html?address=C5:0 | grep -Po '[0-9]+(?=</td><td>(C5:2<|C5:6<|C5:14))'   Not even zero's.  I think you for the help.  I don't mean to seem so helpless, but I'm not sure how to read what the grep is doing.

Comment: @user3727435, my fault, I didn't realize the structure of some rows are slightly different. I just ran the updated answer against your test input. It should work this time. :)

Comment: That works for steps 1 & 2.  Can you help me with assigning the output to a variable and then inserting them into a local database?

Comment: @user3727435 can you post it into a separate question with the db type and structure?